# What is causing the 'invalid datatype' error when using MERGE statement with Oracle PL/SQL table types?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, merge

MERGE using Oracle PL/SQL table type

I want to create/update records using MERGE statement. But getting an error "Invalid datatype".

Table setup

```
CREATE TABLE ps_test01 (id Number primary key,
                        name varchar2(30),
                        active_flag VARCHAR2(1));
                        
                        
CREATE TABLE ps_test02 (id Number primary key,
                        name varchar2(30));
                        
                        
insert into ps_test01 (id, name, active_flag) values (1, 'test01', 'Y');
insert into ps_test01 (id, name, active_flag) values (2, 'test02', 'Y');
insert into ps_test01 (id, name, active_flag) values (3, 'test03', 'Y');

insert into ps_test02 (id, name) values (1, 'test001');
```

Record type

```
create or replace package test_pkg as

TYPE test_rec IS RECORD
   (
      id    number,
      name  varchar2(30),
      active_flag   varchar2(1)
   );
   
   TYPE test_tab_type IS TABLE OF test_rec;

end test_pkg;
/
```

Code that is giving error

```
set SERVEROUTPUT on;
declare
    l_test varchar(10);
    
    cursor cur_ps_test01 IS
        select id, name ,active_flag from ps_test01 where active_flag='Y';
        
    --TYPE test_tab_type is TABLE OF cur_ps_test01%ROWTYPE index by pls_integer;
    test_tab test_pkg.test_tab_type;
    test_tab2 test_pkg.test_tab_type;
        
begin
    
    open cur_ps_test01;
    fetch cur_ps_test01 bulk collect into test_tab;
    close cur_ps_test01;
    
    dbms_output.put_line('number of rows fetched : ' || test_tab.count); 
    
    select * bulk collect into test_tab2 from table(test_tab);
    dbms_output.put_line('number of rows fetched : ' || test_tab2.count); 
    
    
    merge into ps_test02 tab2 -- error was reported on this line
        using ( select id,name,active_flag from table(test_tab) ) tab1
        on (tab1.id = tab2.id)
        when matched then
            update set name = tab1.name
        when not matched then
            insert (id, name) values (tab1.id, tab1.name);
    
end;
/
```

Error

```
00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Please help me resolve this issue.
Appreciate if you could suggest a better way of doing it if any.

Comment: reason for having `select id,name,active_flag from table(test_tab)` in merge is, I don't want to rely on the query. I should be able to have multiple queries that can populate test_tab, that would help me to create/update records in ps_test02 table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restriction on usage of PL/SQL types is listed in [Changes in Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/release_changes.htm#GUID-57E439FB-B196-46CB-857C-0ADAB32D9EA0).

> ### More PL/SQL-Only Data Types Can Cross PL/SQL-to-SQL Interface
>
> As of Oracle Database 12c, it is possible to bind values with PL/SQL-only data types to anonymous blocks (which are SQL statements), PL/SQL function calls in SQL queries and `CALL` statements, and the `TABLE` operator in SQL queries. However:
>
> - ...
> - If the PL/SQL-only data type is an associative array, it cannot be used within a non-query DML statement (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, MERGE) nor in a subquery

You may use `FORALL` statement to perform upsert from a collection:

```
declare
    l_test varchar(10);
    
    cursor cur_ps_test01 IS
        select id, name ,active_flag from ps_test01 where active_flag='Y';
        
    --TYPE test_tab_type is TABLE OF cur_ps_test01%ROWTYPE index by pls_integer;
    test_tab test_pkg.test_tab_type;
    test_tab2 test_pkg.test_tab_type;
    var number;
begin
    
    open cur_ps_test01;
    fetch cur_ps_test01 bulk collect into test_tab;
    close cur_ps_test01;
    
    dbms_output.put_line('number of rows fetched : ' || test_tab.count); 
    
    select * bulk collect into test_tab2 from table(test_tab);
    dbms_output.put_line('number of rows fetched : ' || test_tab2.count); 

    forall i in test_tab.first..test_tab.last
      merge into ps_test02 tab2 -- error was reported on this line
      using (
        select
          test_tab(i).id as id,
          test_tab(i).name as name,
          test_tab(i).active_flag as active_flag
        from dual
      ) tab1
        on (tab1.id = tab2.id)
      when matched then
        update set name = tab1.name
      when not matched then
        insert (id, name) values (tab1.id, tab1.name);
    
end;
/
```

```
1 rows affected

dbms_output:
number of rows fetched : 3
number of rows fetched : 3
```

```
select *
from ps_test02
```

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | test01 |
| 2 | test02 |
| 3 | test03 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/x6cmhN86)

However, it would be better to keep everything at SQL level and do not move the data around with context swithing if you do not perform any extra PL/SQL processing of the fetched data.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your last stement. 
_However, it would be better to keep everything at SQL level and do not move the data around with context swithing if you do not perform any extra PL/SQL processing of the fetched data._

Comment: @RamS You do not need to select into collection just to use this same data in another SQL statement: as already said in the comment to another answer you may combine multiple inputs with `union all` and then `merge` it into the target with a single query. It doesn't require any PL/SQL and, what is more important, doesn't wase PGA with the data that is not required to be here. `MERGE` will work very well for millions of rows while PL/SQL will most probably require batching.

Answer (score 1):

As a frame challenge, PL/SQL and custom types are unnecessary and you can do it all in SQL:

```sql
merge into ps_test02 tab2
using (
  select id, name ,active_flag from ps_test01 where active_flag='Y'
) tab1
on (tab1.id = tab2.id)
when matched then
  update set name = tab1.name
when not matched then
  insert (id, name) values (tab1.id, tab1.name);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IPhK0YQY)

> I should be able to have multiple queries that can populate `test_tab`, that would help me to create/update records in `ps_test02` table.

If you want to use multiple tables then you can use `UNION ALL` to select from multiple tables in the `USING` clause.

Comment: Thanks. But the query itself can be different depending on the context.

Comment: @RamS If the query is going to be different (i.e. have a different output) then you cannot use the same record types for those different outputs. If they have the same output and are just querying different tables and different filter conditions then there is no reason why you need a record type and could not use `UNION ALL` to join all the tables in SQL. I'm still failing to see why PL/SQL is required.

Answer (score 1):

Create a SQL datatype rather than a PL/SQL one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE test_rec AS OBJECT
   (
      id    number,
      name  varchar2(30),
      active_flag   varchar2(1)
   );

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE test_tab_type AS TABLE OF test_rec;
```

Then in your DECLARE section remove the reference to the package:

```
test_tab test_tab_type;
```

Now you can use `test_tab` in SQL statements.